# JavaFX in RaspberryPi 4 with Liberica (Cannot open display ,Cannot create resource)

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I want to develop with JavaFX in my RaspberryPi4, using a 3.5 inch Touch Screen. This is what I've done:
Installed RaspberryPi OS, enable ssh, in the terminal:

```
sudo apt get update
sudo apt get upgrade
```

Installed Liberica with:

```
sudo wget https://download.bell-sw.com/java/11.0.10+9/bellsoft-jdk11.0.10+9-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb
sudo apt install ./bellsoft-jdk11.0.10+9-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.deb
```

I installed the JavaFX armv6hf SDK (11.0.2) from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ and copied to my folder /home/pi/fx

**JavaApplication1**

```
package javaapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaApplication1 extends Application {
    private int count= 0;
    /// ya lo he quitado
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("One more");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                count++;
                System.out.println("Received "+count);
                Alert alerta= new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                alerta.setHeight(200);
                alerta.setWidth(200);
                alerta.showAndWait();
            }
        });
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

Then I execute my JavaApplication1.jar, with:

```
sudo java -jar --module-path /home/pi/fx/armv6hf-sdk/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -Dglass.platform=Monocle JavaApplication1.jar
```

And I got this from the console:

```
Cannot open display
Cannot create resource
Received 1
Cannot create resource
```

The application seems to run, as i get the "Received 1" when I press the center, but this only works once even if I press a lot of times the same point, and the touch screen gets freezed when the app is working. But I cannot see the button or anything, just the desktop freezed.

Comment: By the way, a variation of Liberica includes the JavaFX/OpenJFX libraries. This variation is known as *LibericaFX*. On [their downloads page](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-15-current), it seems the « Full version » option provides LibericaFX.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've also tried with the full version (this time with jdk15 version), I downloaded it, instaled, changed  with ```sudo update-alternatives --config java``` but it shows the same error.

Comment: Check this link: https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_javafx_on_embedded

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have encountered another error so I have created another Question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66714156/javafx-in-raspberry-pi-4-unable-to-open-display).