# JavaFX in Raspberry Pi 4 (Unable to open DISPLAY)

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I was having problems configuring my Raspberry Pi 4, as I explained in my previous question ([JavaFX in RaspberryPi 4 with Liberica (Cannot open display ,Cannot create resource)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694966/javafx-in-raspberrypi-4-with-liberica-cannot-open-display-cannot-create-resour)), so I decided to start over.
I followed the steps on the Gluon tutorial (https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_javafx_on_embedded), (thanks to @José Pereda) but in the end, when I have to execute the line:

```
sudo -E java -Dglass.platform=gtk --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-17/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -cp dist/. hellofx.HelloFX
```

It shows me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$6(GtkApplication.java:173)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:171)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:145)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:281)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:288)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:160)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        ... 5 more
```

I have activated X11Forwarding in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
I remember this error from other Attempts to work with JavaFX, so I tried to change from `-Dglass.platform=gtk` to `-Dglass.platform=Monocle`, but then It shows this fail:

```
Exception in thread "Event Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.DispmanScreen.wrapNativeSymbols()'
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.DispmanScreen.wrapNativeSymbols(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.DispmanScreen.<init>(DispmanScreen.java:34)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.DispmanPlatform.createScreen(DispmanPlatform.java:38)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatform.getScreen(NativePlatform.java:129)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.MonocleApplication.staticScreen_getScreens(MonocleApplication.java:222)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.initScreens(Screen.java:412)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:153)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I'm using a 5.0 inch screen (http://www.lcdwiki.com/5inch_HDMI_Display-B) with an adapter from hdmi to microhdmi.
**After Comments things**
Enabling X11 Forwarding,same errors trying with `sudo -E java -Dglass.platform=gtk --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-17/lib --add-modules javafx.controls export DISPLAY='IP:0.0' -cp dist/. hellofx.HelloFX`
then trying with:

```
sudo -E java -Degl.displayid=/dev/dri/card1 -Dembedded=monocle -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Dmonocle.platform=EGL -Dmonocle.egl.lib=/opt/javafx-sdk-17/lib/libgluon_drm-1.1.0.so -Dprism.verbose=true --module-path /opt/javafx-sdk-17/lib --add-modules javafx.controls -cp dist/. hellofx.HelloFX
```

I get:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Using system sized mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
        succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
[GluonDRM] use GPU at /dev/dri/card1 and display id -1
S0 NOT defined:
[GluonDRM] Device /dev/dri/card1 could be opened, but has no drm capabilities.eglinit failed
eglbind ok
eglCreateWindowSurface called
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6dbd830, pid=904, tid=921
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.9.1+1) (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Raspbian-1deb10u2)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11.0.9.1+1-post-Raspbian-1deb10u2, mixed mode, g1 gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x77830]  strlen+0x0
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/pi/Downloads/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx/hs_err_pid904.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   Unknown
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abortado
```

I used `ulimit -c unlimited`, then used same command, getting:

```
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Using system sized mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
        succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
[GluonDRM] use GPU at /dev/dri/card1 and display id -1
S0 NOT defined:
[GluonDRM] Device /dev/dri/card1 could be opened, but has no drm capabilities.eglinit failed
eglbind ok
eglCreateWindowSurface called
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb6dcc830, pid=923, tid=940
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.9.1+1) (build 11.0.9.1+1-post-Raspbian-1deb10u2)
# Java VM: OpenJDK Server VM (11.0.9.1+1-post-Raspbian-1deb10u2, mixed mode, g1 gc, linux-)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x77830]  strlen+0x0
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: /home/pi/Downloads/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx/core
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/pi/Downloads/samples/CommandLine/Modular/CLI/hellofx/hs_err_pid923.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   Unknown
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Abortado
```

Comment: If you have a physical screen, can you try:
`sudo -E java -Degl.displayid=/dev/dri/card1 -Dembedded=monocle -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Dmonocle.platform=EGL -Dmonocle.egl.lib=/opt/javafx-sdk-17/lib/libgluon_drm.so -Dprism.verbose=true ...`? That should render to your screen (via framebuffer).

Comment: I ran into the same problems time ago. I solved it using bell-sw sdk for arm processors bundling javafx bins compiled for arm https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads-embedded/#/java-13-current

Comment: Why do you need to run as root?  Take a look at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi) for some ideas.  The `xhost +` is likely the simplest for a trusted environment.

Comment: First, thank you all. I've tried  with xhost +, enabling X11 forwarding and using ```export DISPLAY='IP:0.0'``` but I don't know if I implemented it correctly, cause It doesn't seems to change anything. I've tried Liberica in the past, actually my previous cuestion was using it, but I always get these type of errors. I've tried what @José Pereda said, and I think I've made some progress, I'm editing my question so you can see the errors I got now, I think it's something related to capabilities.eglinit, but the more I try, the less I understand. Btw, should I make another question?

Comment: try `/dev/dri/card0` (and see docs!)

Comment: Please don't add things like "SOLVED" to a title. If you managed to solve your own problem, then post an answer detailing the solution, and accept it after the timeout.